# R optim function - Setting constraints for individual parameters

Tags: r, optimization

I am looking to minimize a function using `optim` as follows:

```
yield <- function(data, par) {
  with(data, par[1] + (par[2] + par[3]/par[4])*(1-exp(-par[4]*maturity))/(par[4]*maturity) - (par[3]*exp(-par[4]*maturity)/par[4]))
}
min.RSS <- function(data, par) {
  sum((data$price - 100*exp(-data$maturity*yield(data, par)))^2)
}
result <- optim(par = theta, min.RSS, data = data))
```

The parameters `par[1]` and `par[4]` must be non-negative, while the other two are unconstrained. Is it possible to include these constraints in the `optim` function?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend re-parametrizing the problem so that it is unconstrained. 
Say by mapping the non-negative parameter with a log transform.

Comment: I think your idea is feasible, but can you give an example or link? So that I can find a general solution of different object functions

Answer (score 10):

You can set the constraints for the unconstrained parameters to $\pm \infty$ (and the ceiling for the non-negative parameters to $+\infty$).

```
optim(par=theta, fn=min.RSS, lower=c(0, -Inf, -Inf, 0), upper=rep(Inf, 4),
      method="L-BFGS-B")
```

Technically the `upper` argument is unnecessary in this case, as its default value is `Inf`. However I like to be explicit when specifying bounds.